# Firebase Admin INVALID_APP_OPTIONS error at initializeApp()

Tags: node.js, firebase-admin

I'm trying to connect Instagram OAuth to Firebase through Node.js back-end. I have successfully retrieved Instagram account data including `access_token` which I want to exchange with `firebase-admin`'s `createCustomToken` on my Node.js backend. My objective here is to generate custom token so my Angular app can do `signInWithCustomToken(token)` into my Firebase app. There is no problem on retrieving data from Instagram as I can print my JSON object on console.

The problem is occurred when I want to exchange my `access_token` to Firebase Custom Token.

I have followed [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) from Firebase Admin page for Node.js and I'm facing an error message below

> throw new error_1.FirebaseAppError(error_1.AppErrorCodes.INVALID_APP_OPTIONS, "Invalid Firebase app options passed as the first argument to initializeApp() for the " +
>
> Error: Invalid Firebase app options passed as the first argument to initializeApp() for the app named "[DEFAULT]". The "credential" property must be an object which implements the Credential interface.

Here is my code on related issue.

```js
// authService.js

var fbAdmin = require('firebase-admin');
var serviceAccount = require('./key/key.json');

function createFirebaseToken(instagramID) {

        // I copy & pasted this var from other class
        var config = {
            apiKey: "MY_FIREBASE_APIKEY",
            authDomain: "MY_APP.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://MY_APP.firebaseio.com",
            storageBucket: "MY_APP.appspot.com",
        };

        console.log(fbAdmin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)); // serviceAccount successfully printed on console

        // Error appears when executing this function
        fbAdmin.initializeApp({
            serviceAccount: fbAdmin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
            databaseURL: config.databaseURL
        });

        const uid = `instagram:${instagramID}`;
      
        // Create the custom token.
        console.log(uid);
        return fbAdmin.auth().createCustomToken(uid);
    }
```

It appears that my Node app cannot initialize a connection to `firebase-admin` but I have no idea the solution as I am a beginner on these technologies. Please advice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just stumbled upon on [Firebase Admin Release Notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/node) at version 5.0.0 on May 2017 stated that `serviceAccount` has been removed. So instead of forcing to use `serviceAccount`, I use `credential` instead.

```js
fbAdmin.initializeApp({
  credential: fbAdmin.credential.cert({
      projectId: '<APP_ID>',
      clientEmail: "foo@<APP_ID>.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
      privateKey: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n<MY_PRIVATE_KEY>\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
    }),
  databaseURL: config.databaseURL
});
```

Answer (score 13):

This issue can be resolved by updating firebase-tools, firebase-functions and firebase-admin packages to the latest version.

```
npm install -g firebase-tools@latest
npm install firebase-functions@latest
npm install firebase-admin@latest
```

Refer this [GitHub page](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/99) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

> **Updated Answer**

After continuing to work with this, it seems to be able to call `admin.initializeApp()` without any params, you need to make sure your **`/functions** nodeJs setup is up to date.

In **`/functions`** directory, run this command:

`npm i --save firebase-functions@latest`

Thanks to:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49437619/2162226

.. I am still getting familiar with all the nodeJS/npm details - not sure why, but seems I had to run it a few times for everything to get into place.  That and the `sudo npm install -g firebase-tools` updated as well .

According to official docs, we need to be using at least version Firebase 4.12.0 in order to get the latest cloud functions support: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

> **First Answer**

I ran into the same error message in trying to set up Cloud Functions for Firebase.

Passing in the argument for `admin.initializeApp` solved it for my project:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

After a good amount of search, gratefully found this thread with a post where it has that line of code: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/99 .. because so far haven't seen it anywhere in the docs about that parameter

According to the release docs for Jan. 11, 2018:

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/node

> The admin.initializeApp() method can now be invoked without any arguments. This initializes an app using Google Application Default Credentials, and other AppOptions loaded from the FIREBASE_CONFIG environment variable.

Comment: ✅ This is correct. If you're using firebase admin inside functions then you don't need to pass arguments to `initializeApp`

Answer (score 4):

Kindly use the following snippet, which is mentioned in the Firebase Admin SDK for Node.js. Download the JSON file from the Service Account in the Project Settings and change the path in `serviceAccount`. Also add your `databaseUrl`, which is of the form http://app_name/.firebaseio.com

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "yourDatabaseUrl"
});
```

Answer (score 2):

For those having this issue with `"firebase-admin": "^11.0.0"`, you have to construct the certification passed into `initializeApp()` using `cert` imported from `firebase-admin/app`.

**Example:**

```
import { initializeApp, cert } from "firebase-admin/app";

const admin = initializeApp({
  credential: cert({
    projectId: process.env.MY_PROJECT_ID,
    clientEmail: process.env.MY_PRIVATE_KEY,
    privateKey: process.env.MY_CLIENT_EMAIL,
  }),
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Check what version of firebase-admin module you are using. 
As per the release note of version 5.9.1 
`The admin.initializeApp() method can now be invoked without a credential option. The SDK uses Google Application Default Credentials when initialized this way.`

[release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/node)